# Javascript Price and Quantity adjustment within an array loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, getelementbyid

I'm using a text box as a "quantity" field that updates a < p > with the subtotal of the item. I have this working great for the first item in my while loop (php). Each consecutive item does not adjust the span however.

My PHP:

```
<?php $furniture = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_furniture WHERE furniture_active = '1'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($furniture))
    {
        ?>

    <div class="one-third column">
        <h3><img src="images/<?php echo $row['furniture_image1'];?>" width="300" height="300"></h3>
<?php $furniture_price = $row['furniture_price'];
$furniture_id = $row['furniture_id'];?>
<div id="content">
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="price">
            <p class="furn_itemprice" id="price">&pound;<?php echo $furniture_price;?></p><input name="price[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $furniture_price;?>"><input name="furniture_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $furniture_id;?>">
        </td>
        <td class="quantity">
            <input name="qty[]" type="text" id="quantity" value="" class="calc"/><br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <br />
    <p class="totals" id="subtotal">Sub-total:</p>

</div>     
</p>

<?php } ?>
```

With the javascript function looking like this:

```
var stock = {}
window.onload=function() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
if (inputs[i].type=="text" && inputs[i].id.indexOf('quantity')!=-1) {
  var name = inputs[i].id.replace('quantity','');
  stock[name] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML.replace('£',''))
  inputs[i].onchange=function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var furn_item in stock) {
      var q = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
      total += (isNaN(q) || q=="")?0:parseInt(q)*stock[furn_item]
    }
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML="Sub-total: £"+total.toFixed(2);      

   }  
  }
 }
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do, but I presume somehow the problem lies with the Sub-total:

not having a unique id/name??

Comment: There is no span element in your code.

Comment: @ntaso apologies, I forgot I changed the span to a p. The p in question is <p class="totals" id="subtotal">Sub-total:</p>

Comment: Also, your code generates multiple HTML elements with the same id. An id must be unique on the entire page. That's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Would making the subtotal into subtotal[] fix the issue or would I need to pass in a unique variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could give each element a unique id like:

```
<?php $furniture = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_furniture WHERE furniture_active = '1'");
    $i=0 // init counter
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($furniture))
    {...

   ...
   <p class="furn_itemprice" id="price<?php echo $i++;?>">&pound;<?php ec... // append counter to element id
   ...
```

and

```
  var q = document.getElementById("quantity"+i).value;
```

Also you should not use `mysql*` for new code, it's been superceeded by `mysqli*`

personally I prefer `PDO` for php database connections

Comment: I tried your code like this: for (var furn_item in stock) {
          var q = document.getElementById("quantity"+[i]).value;
          total += (isNaN(q) || q=="")?0:parseInt(q)*stock[furn_item]
        } 

but with no success. It seems like the [i] is outside the loop?

Comment: not `("quantity"+[i])` use `("quantity"+i`) so ineffect you're saying `getElementById("quantity1")` and `getElementById("quantity2")` etc

Comment: Console is telling me: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("quantity"+i).value')

Comment: try console.log(document.getElementById("quantity"+i)); and if not then console.log(i) to make sure its iterating through

Comment: Both return - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: i

Comment: I'm also getting [Error] TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('price').innerHTML')

Comment: `var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {console.log(i)}` you should at least get something there. get that working first. try putting the script at the end of the page

Comment: good `<p id="price<?php echo $i++;?>"></p>` and `for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {console.log(document.getElementById("price"+i))}` should then give you the elements

Comment: I now get [Log] <p class=​"furn_itemprice" id=​"price0">​£100.00​</p>​ (furniture.php, line 197)

[Log] null (furniture.php, line 197)
[Log] <p class=​"furn_itemprice" id=​"price2">​£200.00​</p>​ (furniture.php, line 197)

Comment: right so now you can set `document.getElementById("subtotal"+i).val(document.getElementById("quantity"+i).val()*parseFloat(document.getElementById("price"+i).val()))` (for example) (though im guessing a little there as I usually use jquery)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48084/discussion-between-tomantford-and-andrew)

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, your code generates multiple HTML elements with the same id. An id must be unique on the entire page. That's why your code doesn't work.

What you want to achieve is to give different ids for every row / piece of furniture and bind the JavaScript handlers accordingly. It's easier with jQuery. You could create quantity fields that have an attribute that contains the price:

```
<input name="qty[]" type="text" data-price="<?php echo $furniture_price;?>" value="" class="quantity"/>
```

Then, in jQuery, you could get all elements with the class quantity:

```
var sum = 0;
$(".quantity").each(function() {
    sum += $(this).val() * $(this).attr('data-price');
});
$("#subtotal").text(sum);
```

So, you can achieve something similar without jQuery, for sure. I hope this gives you an idea how to solve your problem.